# c language rounding up on Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, rounding

I'm pretty new to coding and languages.
I'm using Xcode and have input and printed to screen a table of data 20x20 in size.

I just wondered what is the easiest way to get all that data rounded up to 3dp?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe `%.3f` — but you really need to supply code (and sample data — but not a 20x20 example; maybe 5x5 or 4x4 or 3x3 would suffice) and actual and required output.